# Newest Microsoft Chart and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

Recently ASP.NET developer launched its newest control, Charting control. ([Microsoft Chart](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en)). Does this compatible with ASP.NET MVC, or its only compatible with ASP.NET WebForm ?

Comment: See Also: [New asp.net charting controls - will they work with MVC (eventually)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-aspnet-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually#320891)

Comment: I've been working the last days in a component( http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/ ) for charts in MVC using fusion charts. If you wnat take a look, it is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 10):

[They are compatible with MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/25/combining-asp-net-mvc-and-asp-net-charting-controls.aspx)