# How do I create 3D pie chart? -Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I have seen Microsoft charting control @ [here](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx).

It has good demonstration for displaying bar chart in MVC.

On scottgu's blog There are plenty of examples but they are using server controls (i.e `<asp:CHRT runat"server">`.
This is also supported in MVC by Modifying web.config.

but as we should avoid using server control as postback is not supported in MVC, we should
render it as shown in "without code behind page" example.

Exactly like This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-asp-net-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually).

Now I would like to know **how other chart types** (like pie chart) can be created in controller?

Answer (score 5):

I like google charts. Just write a HTMLHelper to render the correct URL.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 1):

Try using 3rd party flash charting controls like [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com). They can be configured via a simple XML file and get their data from static or generated XML or CSV files or streams.

Answer (score 0):

[New asp.net charting controls - will they work with MVC (eventually)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-asp-net-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually)

Something that was created quite a while ago, but is relevant to this topic.