# .NET Charting and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, charts

Anyone have an minimal example of ASP.NET MVC and dotnetcharting.com control lying around?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[New asp.net charting controls - will they work with MVC (eventually)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-aspnet-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually)

Answer (score 1):

You can download ASP.NET samples of the .NET Charting control [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591). It gives a wide range of examples and provides code snippets to go with.

Comment: I updated the chart samples for .NET 4.0 and added two additional projects -- ChartsWithMVC and ChartsWithoutWebForms for anyone who wants to see one way to utilize the asp.net charts in a non-web form world. Download sample code here: http://develocity.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-chart-controls-without-web-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft ASP.NET chart control that James mentions with the MVC Framework.  The control was designed for use with WebForms, but it will work from an MVC View as long as you don't need to handle postback events.  If you do, you may want to consider developing a hybrid solution with WebForms pages where charting is required and MVC for the rest of the site.