# Create a Gannt chart using mschart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mschart

Is it possible to create a Gannt Chart using [MS Chart](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)?

The chart will be created based on data returned from a web service.

We are using ASP.Net MVC. From other posts it appears that MS Chart does not support ASP.Net MVC. If this is the case we can place the chart on a web forms page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is definitely possible. You can for instance use the "Range bar" chart type to create a Gannt chart.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it :) If not, and you need further description, ask away.

Answer (score 0):

MS Chart does work with MVC, this has been covered many times here.

See this post: [New asp.net charting controls - will they work with MVC (eventually)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-aspnet-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually#320891)

Comment: @Lazerus, yes I know, I say so in my post, but will MS Chart produce a Gannt chart?