# Is there a free chart report tool on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report, charts

Can anyone recommend a free tool for generating Charts compatible with ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this free web control from Microsoft:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

I tried it with regular web application, not MVC though. Works alright, a little finicky in some details.

What kind of charts you need to deal with? Some time ago I was looking for Gantt chart control, and really did not find any good free ones.

Regards, Anvar

Comment: More info on how to get these charts to work with ASP.NET MVC [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-aspnet-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually#320891) and [here](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected they work for both MVC and regular web apps similarly well.

Comment: are these all server side charts? or can they be created using javascript? HMTL % compatible?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image_charts.html).

To clarify, GCT isn't specific to ASP.NET MVC.  It's a hosted thing that you can call with Javascript.  I've use it in MVC and regular ASP.NET project alike.  Very clean and nice.

For instance, open your browser and go here:

https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

You'll see this:

[image]

Comment: Sure, and that's an advantage.  Offload the chart rendering to someone else (just like you offload your js, css content to a CDN).

Comment: If you can do that. It won't be possible in some scenarios, such as Intranet applications with business-sensitive data.

Comment: Good point on intranet apps.  Not necessarily, on biz sensitive data.  I went through that myself, while working on an app, but discovered that you can usually abstract the data pretty easily such that nothing useful is transmitted.  In other words, your data points (10, 20, 30) are meaningless and you leave words (title, legend, etc) off of the GCT-rendered image and add those elsewhere.

Comment: Google Chart is a useful and easy to use tool. There are some minor issues I found when trying to define a custom width for labels on Y axis... I was not able to tweak it. Also we cannot expect Google to fix and make it quickly better, and our end-customer cannot complain about it, since there is no way to fix it. I think Google could improve it, but maybe they are busy with a lot of projects.

Answer (score 0):

[Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/)

The advantages of the Google Chart Tools are:

- A rich gallery of visualizations  provided as:

  - Image charts - using a simple URL request to a Google chart server
  - Interactive charts - using a Google developed JavaScript library
  - Can read live data from a variety of data sources
  - Simple to use and free

Comment: Yes, if I'm offering my site as intranet only, it'll won't work if customer doesn't have internet connection

Comment: It would have been nice to include that in your question, in this case google charts wont work. Fusion Charts might be another option, plus they are fancy!

Answer (score 0):

you can use google chart tool. its easy to use and woks good.
for refrence you can go through below url

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization

hope i would help you.