# How to use charting in mvc?

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to use chart and graph in my MVC2 Application?
How to use?
Please Suggest.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will find useful links here
[Charting and MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-asp-net-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually)