# ASP.Net MVC Charts

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-charts

In my project i read the xml file and store the XML file into SQL Db.
And then i get the input from sql db ,Display the result in Chart,Graphs...
Is It possible ?

Can u pls suggest me....?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with MS Chart in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another SO post discussing the same

[New asp.net charting controls - will they work with MVC (eventually)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-aspnet-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually#320891)

Answer (score 0):

You can use google sharting api...really easy to integrate it into your mvc application.
here is a simple example how it works [Working Example](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/johnvpetersen/archive/2010/04/05/adding-google-charts-to-your-asp-mvc-applications.aspx)

hope this helps.