# How to use chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

How can we use chart control in MVC, I need sample code with little coding, just to understand the approach of creating chart controls in MVC, like how to bind data etc.

Tried few samples but not able to understand the approach.

I just tried to use `@Html.Chart()` in my view but I'm unable to use it.

NOTE: I don't want to use any 3rd party controls.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736622/microsoft-charting-mvc-3-and-razor

Comment: Have you tried [google](http://bit.ly/R16RGK)? Maybe the first or second result? :)

Comment: May be you can search for some tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is my razor view code,Work perfectly for me.

```
@{
        var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
          .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
          .AddSeries(
              chartType: "Bubble",
              name: "Employee",
              xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
              yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });     
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> 
            <div>
                @key.Write()
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note: This render resposne in image format.