# Problem with asp.net and charts

Tags: asp.net, charts, sqldatasource

I have to use charts for a web site and I'm not able to make them work at all.

It seems easy: you declare a sql data source and the chart will use that data source, but it doesn't work. Instead of the chart, a "broken image" picture appears. I've tried using different browsers and placing the sql data source in different places, but it didn't work.

I'm using vs2010, and the sql data source has been tested and it returns the values ok.

Since I can't find the problem in the code, I write it here:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<h2>Title</h2>

<br />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringChart1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [companyID], [numberOfVisits] FROM [Company]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="companyID" 
            YValueMembers="numberOfVisits">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>

<br />

</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the event log? sometimes problems can be associated with the image location used by the chart control not existing or the app pool not having write access.

Comment: any output says error, but I'm not sure if it's the event log...
NOTE: I'm using MVC 2, maybe it's important

Comment: Check the event log for more detailed errors: http://www.devtopics.com/how-to-check-the-application-event-log-for-errors/

Comment: Checked, but anything important :_(

Comment: you mentioned that you are using MVC, but the code above is webforms code...

Comment: here is an SO question discussing using it with MVC, maybe it provides some insight for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-asp-net-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually

Comment: Ok, so is that?
I feel stupid, vs toolbox let me add that chart, so I thought that I could use it with mvc...
I'll check that link and reply the results here. Thank you Zach.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Register Declaration, you need to modify your web.config file to get the Chart to work.

**Edit**: changed 'verg' to 'verb'

```
    <httpHandlers>
       <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers
```

and
Check to see if you have at the top of your page the Register declaration:

```
<%@ Register Assembly = "System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: Also, if the chart needs to work on a post, POST needs to be added to the verb list in the httphandler, or just change it to verb="*"

Comment: I've already have those lines in both files (web.config and .aspx), so that may not be the problem... <httpHandlers> is within <system.web>, is that ok?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I edit because I've just realised of the verb placement.
anyway, it's still not working

Those lines are in web.config, they may help
  <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>

Comment: <httpHandlers> is supposed to go inside <system.web>, which is good.
I believe you only need to define verb inside the web.config. Have you tried verb="*" instead of verb="GET,HEAD" (or post)

Comment: unfortunately using verb=" * " returns the same result :(

Comment: by the way, I'm not using any code-behind like Page_Load or something like that because I think that I don't need it, do I?

Comment: Don't think so, might be a silly thing but i noticed your series has no ChartType, try adding a chart type: <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="companyID" 
            YValueMembers="numberOfVisits" ChartType="Line">

Comment: I've added the ChartType and the result is the same, argh!

Comment: Try changing the version from 4.0.0.0 to 3.5.0.0 or 2.0.0.0 in the httpHandlers add tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that into asp charts control but I do recommend Visifire chart control which is powered by silverlight. Look at this example http://www.visifire.com/blog/2009/05/21/creating-silverlight-charts-from-sql-data-using-aspnet-and-visfire/

I managed to do a proof-of-concept within two days, almost one, and succeding in present SQL data (Datasets) in a silverlight chart. Once it's there, visifire is extremly powerful (and free). It gives you possibility to zoom, label datapoints, axellabels, realtime data etc.

If you want to go the manage-code approach you get even more possibilities. good luck. Check out the example link and you realize how easy it is. 
We use it today with great success.

I forgot to say, you do not need to know how to program RIA/Silverlight xaml...