# How can I set the series color on a chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I am using [System.Web.Helpers.Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

```
Namespace:  System.Web.Helpers
Assembly:   System.Web.Helpers (in System.Web.Helpers.dll)
```

Is there a way to set a series color? This light yellow is hard to spot...

[image: temperature over time]

Chart code:

```
new Chart(width: w, height: h, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
    .AddLegend("Legenda")
    .SetYAxis(min: 0, max: 30)
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Temperatura",
        chartType: DataVisualization.SeriesChartType.FastLine.ToString(),
        xValue: dataRange.Select(d => d.RecordDate.ToString("dd/MM")).ToList(),
        yValues: dataRange.Select(d => d.TemperatureAvg).ToList())
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Ponto de orvalho",
        chartType: DataVisualization.SeriesChartType.FastLine.ToString(),
        xValue: dataRange.Select(d => d.RecordDate.ToString("dd/MM")).ToList(),
        yValues: dataRange.Select(d => d.DewAvg).ToList())
    .Write();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783502/how-to-set-chart-series-colors-in-mvc-3

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the theme and define color for the series. Something like below:

```
string customSeriesColor = @"<Chart BorderlineDashStyle=""Solid"" BorderWidth=""1"">

    <ChartAreas>
         <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All""> 
      <AxisY Interval=""50""> 
        <LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 70px"" /> 
      </AxisY> 
<AxisX Interval=""200""> 
        <LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 70px"" /> 
      </AxisX>
    </ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
 <Titles>
        <Title Font=""Times New Roman, 16pt, style=Bold"" Name=""Title"" Text=""Costs"">
        </Title>
    </Titles>
  <Series>
     <Series Name=""Temperatura"" BorderWidth=""1"" Color=""Red"">
     </Series>
<Series Name=""Ponto de orvalho"" BorderWidth=""1"" Color=""Blue"">
     </Series>

   </Series>
    <Legends>
        <Legend _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""Transparent"" Font=""Trebuchet MS, 12.25pt, style=Bold"" IsTextAutoFit=""False"" />
    </Legends>
    <BorderSkin SkinStyle=""Emboss"" />
  </Chart>";
```

and your chart code will be following:

```
new Chart(width: w, height: h, theme: customSeriesColor)
```