# Setting a Constant Size for a Pie Chart with External Labels

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, charts

All,

Hopefully the title should say it all.  We're switching from the System.Web.Helpers to the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization charting controls because there's simply not enough options available in the former.  Using some code "borrowed" from [Simon Steele](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319835/new-asp-net-charting-controls-will-they-work-with-mvc-eventually/) (thanks!), I've gotten the basic charts showing on my form, and altered the code to add the custom property PieLabelStyle to Outside.

But, there's a side effect:  the pies with one XY pair are larger than those with multiple XY pairs because the chart adjusts the pie size based on the fixed external width of the image.  Labels on both sides thus force a smaller pie, which looks awful on the page.

There's probably a property among the hundreds in the namespace.  Anyone done this before and solved the problem?

Thanks

Jim Stanley
Blackboard Connect

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today and found this answer:

```
<asp:Chart>
    <Series>
        <asp:Series CustomProperties="MinimumRelativePieSize=60"/>
    </Series>
</asp:chart>
```